# “A” tag wrapping “IMG” seems incorrect size. (32 * 32px is shown as 38 * 21px)

Tags: html, css

The following is my issued codes (http://jsfiddle.net/dz754deg/1/).

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32/"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32/"/>
</a>
```

The result isn’t strange seemingly. But if I check it with browser’s built-in developer tools, the `a` tag has an incorrect size. In Chrome (latest version), the `img` tag is normal (32 * 32px). But the `a` tag is odd (38 * 21px or 32 * 21px).

This image might help:

[image: You can see that the A element has an inconsistent size]

Firefox has the same issue. I think it isn’t browser-specific.
How can I fix it gracefully?

Comment: I guess that’s mainly because `<a>` isn’t a block-level element. Assigning `display:inline-block` to `a` would help something… but then for me it’s still 32 × 35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two styles make the blocks appear correctly:

```css
a{
    display:inline-block;
}
img{
    display:block;
}
```

It’s because of how the `inline` and `block` level elements are rendered. You can still *click* on an `inline` link that is wrapped around the image everywhere where the image is but it just *looks* as if you couldn’t.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dz754deg/2/)

**Screenshots** as rendered in Firefox:

[image: IMG element][image: A element]

Comment: Instead of `img{display:block}`, `vertical-align:middle` (and most values other than `baseline`) can also be used.

Comment: Thanks. It works great. But when I apply your solution to my real code, The height of the `a` tag fits to the parent's. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz754deg/3/) I'm sorry because simplified the code more than necessary. But I want to fit width and height of course `img` tags and also the `a` tags. Please help me.

Comment: @Chungs I think something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dz754deg/4/) shoud fix it.